# SQL update column3 after group by column1 and compare value in column2

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table T that look like this: where id is the unique auto-increment primary key. Difference column is default to 0. I want to UPDATE only the difference of largestId - secondLargestId in each id_str group while the rest remains unchanged.

```
    id_str     id             Value   Difference
    2380        1             21.01       0
    2380        3             22.04       0
    2380        5             22.65       0
    2380        8             23.11       0
    2380       10             35.21       0
    20100       2             37.07       0
    20100       4             38.17       0
    20100       6             38.97       0
    20103       7             57.98       0
    20103       9             60.83       0
```

The result I want is:

```
    id_str     id             Value   Difference
    2380        1             21.01       0
    2380        3             22.04       0
    2380        5             22.65       0
    2380        8             23.11       0
    2380       10             35.21      12.1
    20100       2             37.07       0
    20100       4             38.17       0
    20100       6             38.97      0.8
    20103       7             57.98       0
    20103       9             60.83      2.85
```

How can I write the query?

Comment: your logic for the update is not clear  .. how you get 12.1 ? and why you want update only ro id=10 ?  (the same for 0.8 and 6  ... )

Comment: What should the behavior be if there is only 1 record with a given id_str value?

Comment: @scaisEdge   As I described the logic is use the row where : Id is the max in that id_str group. Then use MaxId row - SecondLargestId row. So 12.1 is 35.21 - 23.11. (10 is the largest in that id_str group)   Same for 0.8 and 2.85

Comment: @YellowBedwetter then remain the Difference column unchanged with default value 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable 
  ( id_str VARCHAR(10),
    id INTEGER,
    value_ DECIMAL(7,5),
    difference DECIMAL(7,5)
  );


INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(2380,1,21.01,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(2380,3,22.04,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(2380,5,22.65,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(2380,8,23.11,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(2380,10,35.21,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(20100,2,37.07,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(20100,4,38.17,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(20100,6,38.97,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(20103,7,57.98,0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(20103,9,60.83,0);

UPDATE SomeTable,
       (SELECT T1.id AS id_updt,
               T1.value_ - T2.value_ AS diff_updt
          FROM (SELECT id_str,
                       id,
                       value_,
                       (
                       CASE id_str
                           WHEN @curStr THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
                           ELSE @curRow := 1 
                            AND @curStr := id_str
                        END
                       ) AS rnk

                  FROM SomeTable,
                       (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curStr := '') r
                 ORDER
                    BY id_str DESC,
                       id DESC
               ) AS T1
         INNER 
          JOIN (SELECT id_str,
                       id,
                       value_,
                       (
                       CASE id_str
                           WHEN @curStr THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
                           ELSE @curRow := 1 
                            AND @curStr := id_str
                        END
                       ) AS rnk

                  FROM SomeTable,
                       (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curStr := '') r
                 ORDER
                    BY id_str DESC,
                       id DESC
               ) AS T2     
            ON T1.id_str = T2.id_str
           AND T1.rnk = 1
           AND T2.rnk = 2
       ) AS UPDT
   SET SomeTable.difference = UPDT.diff_updt
 WHERE SomeTable.id = UPDT.id_updt;
```

**Deprecated solution** - This will work for a DBMS that supports the rank function.

```
UPDATE SomeTable
  FROM ( SELECT RNK1.id AS id_updt,
                RNK1.value_ - RNK2.value_ AS diff_updt
           FROM (SELECT id_str,
                        RANK() OVER
                           ( PARTITION BY id_str
                                 ORDER BY id DESC
                           ) AS id_rnk
                  FROM SomeTable
                ) AS RNK1
          INNER
           JOIN (SELECT id_str,
                        RANK() OVER
                           ( PARTITION BY id_str
                                 ORDER BY id DESC
                           ) - 1 AS id_rnk_decrement
                  FROM SomeTable
                ) AS RNK2
             ON RNK1.id_str = RNK2.id_str
            AND RNK1.id_rnk = RNK2.id_rnk_decrement
          WHERE RNK1.id_rnk = 1
       ) AS UPDT
   SET SomeTable.difference_ = UPDT.diff_updt
 WHERE SomeTable.id = UPDT.id_updt;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Do you know what the MySQL syntax is for this? I get a syntax error around FROM ( SELECT TMP.id AS id_updt,
                TMP.value_ - TMP_2.value

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought MySQL supported the rank function. Let me rework this.

Comment: @Dylan Sorry for the delay, I've added a MySQL solution.

Comment: I used your code but there seemed to be some error. The other answer below worked though. Still, I appreciate your help and effort !

Comment: @Dylan Can you share the error you are getting? I spent a bit of time on that and the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38ad1d/1/0 looks correct.

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'retweet_count_' in 'field list'. retweet_count is the "Value" in my database. I don't know whether it has anything to do with the "_" in naming of the column.

Comment: @Dylan Yeah, I bet it's the underscore. I just put it there because "value" is keyword.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the naming, it worked now. Let me do some test on it and give you the feedback

Comment: Even though it looks long and complicated , your code actually runs faster at 0.062 sec while the other one at 0.235 sec. This advantage may be larger as the database grow larger. So I think this is a better answer

Comment: @Dylan create an index on `(id_str, id)` and you will see, that my query scales pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the two greatest ids per group with the following query:

```
select t1.id_str, max(t1.id) as id1, (
    select max(t2.id)
    from mytable t2
    where t2.id_str = t1.id_str
      and t2.id < max(t1.id)
) as id2
from mytable t1
group by t1.id_str;
```

Result:

```
| id_str | id1 | id2 |
|--------|-----|-----|
|   2380 |  10 |   8 |
|  20100 |   6 |   4 |
|  20103 |   9 |   7 |
```

Use it as subquery in your update statement:

```
update mytable u
join (
    select t1.id_str, max(t1.id) as id1, (
        select max(t2.id)
        from mytable t2
        where t2.id_str = t1.id_str
          and t2.id < max(t1.id)
    ) as id2
    from mytable t1
    group by t1.id_str
) t on t.id1 = u.id
join mytable t1 on  t1.id = t.id1
join mytable t2 on  t2.id = t.id2
set u.Difference = t1.Value - t2.Value;
```

The table will now contain:

```
| id_str | id | Value | Difference |
|--------|----|-------|------------|
|   2380 |  1 | 21.01 |          0 |
|   2380 |  3 | 22.04 |          0 |
|   2380 |  5 | 22.65 |          0 |
|   2380 |  8 | 23.11 |          0 |
|   2380 | 10 | 35.21 |       12.1 |
|  20100 |  2 | 37.07 |          0 |
|  20100 |  4 | 38.17 |          0 |
|  20100 |  6 | 38.97 |        0.8 |
|  20103 |  7 | 57.98 |          0 |
|  20103 |  9 | 60.83 |       2.85 |
```

http://rextester.com/CCO40873